# Display particular category image in stencil bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working in Mega menu and i have add some new functionality i have display less than two category image in my mega menu how can i display? I am use stancil framwork.

i have use this code:

```
<ul class="col-2">
    <li class="menuFeat">
        <a href="#">Image:
        {{category.subcategories.image}}    
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

project link:
http://ptg6.mybigcommerce.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you want to show each category image into your mega menu so let's go if I am right.

**Step 1:** Open your admin end and then open your themes file editor I hope you know well how to open it.

**Step 2**  Go to components-> common -> navigation-list.html

**Step 3**  replace`<a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>`   with this one `<a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}<img src="{{getImage image "thumbnail"}}"></a>`

check screenshot http://prntscr.com/fhocrk

and it will look like this one  http://deepak-diwan-s-store.mybigcommerce.com/

check all menus in my store, one more thing category should have images assigned from the back end.

Comment: Hi, this code is not working on home page why? i am trying to display 3 category in home page. Can you guide how can i fix it?

Comment: Your website is in maintenance mode how I can check and it is working fine in my end I have currently changed the theme.

Comment: Hey @jaydeep you did not upload images from you admin end to your subcategory, please upload the images for your category and then apply the code.

Comment: hi @raj how can i display related product in listing page ? any idea ? i am working in stencil framwork.

Comment: you can call the related product object on the category page and it will easily work.

Comment: hi i am trying to call related product code but this code does't work. You have a code? and any idea about that?