# How to display category images in category menu in big commerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working on a Bigcommerce store and I have inserted images in categories.

I want to insert category images and subcategory images in category menus (navigation menu) as a icon.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Open your admin end and then open your themes file editor I hope you know well how to open it.

**Step 2** Go to components-> common -> navigation-list.html

**Step 3** replace`<a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>` with this one `<a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}<img src="{{getImage image "thumbnail"}}"></a>`

check screenshot http://prntscr.com/fhocrk

make sure the category images should be added from admin end.

[Display particular category image in stencil bigcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405348/display-particular-category-image-in-stencil-bigcommerce/44449645#44449645)